# Validate particular cell value

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, cells

I need to validate that the value in a particular cell in my datagridview falls within a certain range (0 - 99.9999) and if not, cancel the user edit.  What I have so far is validating a column that it is a double data type and that it is > 0.  That works.  But now I need to validate each particular cell in that column since they all will need to be validated for particular numeric ranges.  Each cell will have a different range of values it can accept.

```
 Private Sub dgvPidVals0_cellValidating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles dgvPidVals0.CellValidating
    'Me.dgvPIDStatus0.Rows(e.ColumnIndex).ErrorText = ""
    Dim newDouble As Double

    Select Case e.ColumnIndex
        Case 1
            If Not Double.TryParse(e.FormattedValue.ToString(), newDouble) OrElse newDouble < 0 Then
                e.Cancel = True
                MessageBox.Show("PID Parameters values must be non-negative numeric values only!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                dgvPidVals0.CancelEdit()

                If dgvPidVals0.Rows(5).Cells(1).Value > 99.9999 Then
                    e.Cancel = True
                    MessageBox.Show("Output Filter Value must be less than 100.0!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                    dgvPidVals0.CancelEdit()
                End If

            End If
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Where are you stuck now? What have you tried? What is your question...?

Answer (score 0):

Tez, I've already tried that exact code and it doesn't work.  I'm stumped as to why not.  The first If statement of the code works fine.  The Else If portion does not work.  I punch in a value greater than 100 in the DGV's cell and it takes (when it should not).  I then click on the form again, and the Message box appears.  I can't do anything at that point since every click of the DGV will make the message box show up.  In the end, I used the CellEndEdit event handler to check that values in each of the cells that I'm evaluating fall within a certain range.  It's a hacked way of doing it I think and I would think there is a better, more clean way of doing it.  But....it works.  Still open to answers from others as to what to do or if using the CellEndEdit event is the actual way to do it.

```
 Private Sub dgvPidVals0_CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvPidVals0.CellEndEdit

    If dgvPidVals0.Rows(0).Cells(1).Value > 6.14 Then
        dgvPidVals0.Rows(0).Cells(1).Value = axis0Parameters(61) 'Load previous value into the cell
        MessageBox.Show("Proportional Gain Value must be <= 6.14!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End If

    If dgvPidVals0.Rows(1).Cells(1).Value > 58.94 Then
        dgvPidVals0.Rows(1).Cells(1).Value = axis0Parameters(62)
        MessageBox.Show("Integral Gain Value must be <= 58.94!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End If

    If dgvPidVals0.Rows(2).Cells(1).Value > 0.1753 Then
        dgvPidVals0.Rows(2).Cells(1).Value = axis0Parameters(63)
        MessageBox.Show("Differential Gain Value must be <= 0.1753!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End If

    If dgvPidVals0.Rows(3).Cells(1).Value > 5 Then
        dgvPidVals0.Rows(3).Cells(1).Value = axis0Parameters(64)
        MessageBox.Show("Feed Forward Value must be <= 5!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End If

    If dgvPidVals0.Rows(4).Cells(1).Value > 1.5 Then
        dgvPidVals0.Rows(4).Cells(1).Value = axis0Parameters(65)
        MessageBox.Show("Rate Feed Forward Value must be <= 1.5!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End If

    If dgvPidVals0.Rows(5).Cells(1).Value > 100 Then
        dgvPidVals0.Rows(5).Cells(1).Value = axis0Parameters(39)
        MessageBox.Show("Output Filter Value must be <= 100.0!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End If

    slider1.Value = dgvPidVals0.Item(1, 0).Value
    slider2.Value = dgvPidVals0.Item(1, 1).Value
    slider3.Value = dgvPidVals0.Item(1, 2).Value
    slider4.Value = dgvPidVals0.Item(1, 3).Value
    slider5.Value = dgvPidVals0.Item(1, 4).Value
    slider6.Value = dgvPidVals0.Item(1, 5).Value
End Sub
```